# ArcGIS WebApp Iframe not loading in mobile

Tags: arcgis-mobile

I'm building a web application which used both by desktop and mobile users.
I have a component that represenets an iframe that sources an ArcGIS Web Application

When a desktop user enters the page, the ArcGIS WebApp loading inside the iframe and everything works fine.
but, when a mobile user enters the page, the iframe just doesn't stop to try and load itself again and again.
im adding a screenshot both for mobile & desktop with devTools console open.
(as far as I see - "jimu.js" trying to load itself again and again)
Tested & Working from desktop with browsers: Firefox, Chrome.
Tested & Not working from mobile with browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Samsung Internet, Safari.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="esrimap-daddy" style="background: '#EDEDED';">&nbsp;</div>
```

JS Looks like this:

```
let href = 'https://gis.ris-eng.co.il/portal/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=73e574289ff0479f8674be9e4b7fc041&query=1845703ce4a-layer-70,num,' + num;

let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.width = "100%";
iframe.height = '900px';
iframe.frameBorder = '0';
iframe.src = href;
    
let divMap = document.querySelector("div#esrimap-daddy");
divMap.appendChild(iframe);
```

---

These are the screenshots:
[image]
[image: mobile screenshot]

I'm adding a screenshot that shows the ArcGIS WebApp, which is working in mobile, but not in iframe. "jimu.js" is loaded
[image]